# Error in downloading a file from folder,path is in database language used

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error message

```
"Requested URL: /selva/DDL COMMANDS.doc"
```

actually my file path should be

```
URL:/selva/Docs/DDL COMMANDS.doc
```

Code i have used :

```
LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
string filePath = gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
Response.ContentType = "application/doc";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/+ filePath + "));
Response.End();
```

in aspx

What may be the mistake can any one help me soon pls. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format this code. It's unreadable.

Comment: You need to format your code so it's more readable, hitting space 4 times gives you a code block in your question. Also, what is your DataKey in your gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=xxxxxx.doc");
Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("/xxxxxxx.doc"));
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

[**Reference Link**](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/02/saveupload-files-in-folder-and-download.html)

Comment: sir, its like downloading list of files available in gridview

Comment: you are also use `Gridview` does not matter wheather it is `Grid` or simple `link` if you are trying to download file then you have to write that code.

Comment: my file is inside an folder named docs how to set path for it

Comment: By using `Server.MapPath('~/YourPath')